# Firefox and Chrome with different color of #fadcc7

Tags: html, css, colors

The representation picture of the difference follows below:
[image]

the more yellowish one is from chrome meanwhile the one more skin like pinkish is from firefox.

Could someone tell what's going on given that's not even a subtle difference, it's quite different enough to be seen as different colors(one like yellow, the other one like peach like)?

It does not help that after the stack overflow paste of the screenshot both colors aren't quite the same from the HEX in the title...

Comment: can you post your css for this color property. also , are you using any webkits? did you test it in rgb codes?

Comment: it's in the root as a variable `:root { --background:#fadcc7; }` and both body and html elements are set with `background-color:var(--background)`

Comment: try finding the rgb code for it and use it without root property. check if the color is different in both browsers and tell me.

Comment: also check if using a different color with root raises the same problem. there are some variations within some shades which different browsers understand differently. so check it.

Answer (score 0):

This is already existing issue Please check :[Chromium issue #44872.](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=44872)